# Expanding arrays of intervals in Arrayfire

Tags: vectorization, arrayfire

I have three Arrayfire arrays that look like this:

```
Array 1  Array 2  Array 3
20       5        9
3        0        0
9        4        8
0        20       22
...      ...      ...
```

Using Arrayfire, I would like to generate 2 new arrays. The first should contain values from Array 1. Each value should be repeated a number of times dictated by the interval between the corresponding values in Array 2 (inclusive) and Array 3 (exclusive). The second array should contain an expansion of the values within each interval for each value from Array 1. Sorry if that's not clear. Here's the desired output to hopefully clarify:

```
Array 1  Array 2
20       5
20       6
20       7
20       8
9        4
9        5
9        6
9        7
0        20
0        21
...      ...
```

The order of the output doesn't matter.

Thanks, in advance, from an Arrayfire novice.